# Is it possible know when a model has been called in Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby

I would like that know when any class or any class method yours is called. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

For exemple

```
class Example

  def obeserver_method
    p "this class has been called."
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

I tried implement a observer, based in the Observe Pattern of the Ruby, but returns an error...

```
require "observer"

class AAnyClass
  extend Observable

  changed

end

module AnObserver

  extend self

  def call constant
    p "Constant #{constant} has been called."
  end

  def observe constant
    constant.add_observer(self, call(constant))
  end

end
#=> returns "Constant AAnyClass has been called."
AnObserver.observe AAnyClass
# must return "Constant AAnyClass has been called."
AAnyClass
# must return "Constant AAnyClass has been called."
AAnyClass
```

This is the error: `` `add_observer': observer does not respond to `Constant AAnyClass has been called.' (NoMethodError) ``

**UPDATE**

The new implementation

```
class AAnyClass
  extend Observable
  changed
  notify_observers self
end

module AnObserver

  extend self

  def call constant
    p "Constant #{constant} has been called."
  end

  def observe constant
    constant.add_observer(self, :call)
  end

end
```

Doesn't return an error, but nothing is seen.

Comment: when you call it you know it :) add more info to the question, specify it

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I added information.

Comment: The second parameter in add_observer is a symbol corresponding to the method that will be called - you are passing in the result of calling 'call' which is the string "Constant AAnyClass has been called." you would need to write it `constant.add_observer(self, :call)`. However this won't produce the desired result. In your class definition you call 'changed', this will only fire when the class is instantiated (same reason as in my other comment)

Comment: you would also need a call to notify_observers...

Comment: I implemented the changes, but now nothing is seen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`logger`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger):

```
class Example
  def obeserver_method
    # some logic
    Rails.logger.info  "this class has been called."
  end
end
```

Than, in your logfile you will see the info about method call.

## EDIT

From comments:

> Sorry, suppose that run rails c on terminal, and suppose that my
>   project have a model `Example` with attributes, `id`, `attr1`, `attr2`...,
>   when I type `Example` and press Enter I would like that a **observer** run
>   a routine, for example, connect to a specific database.

Even though I do not clearly see how typing `Example` in console is a good trigger for some actions, but anyway, you basically named the tool in your question: **Observer**.

Check out [`Observable` class](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html) which ease implementing the *Observer pattern*.

Comment: I think it's not quite it. Not to store or display an information, it's to perform a routine. If I call ```Example``` a method must know.

Comment: @rplaurindo 1. I do not understand, how are you calling a class? 2. how should method "know" anything? 3. What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: @rplaurindo do you want `obeserver_method` to store info about amount of times `Example` was referenced?

Comment: Sorry, suppose that run ```rails c``` on terminal, and suppose that my project have a model "Example" with attributes, id, attr1, attr2..., when I type "Example" and press Enter I would like that a observer run a routine, for example, connect to a specific database.

Comment: I updated with an attempt to implement a observer, but returns an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to keep track of all the method calls in your entire application without having to parse through you log file or add logger calls you could install [Coverband](https://github.com/danmayer/coverband). Coverband keeps very detailed track of all of the methods that are called in you rails app. You can look at stats by source file and drill down.

[image: coverband high level view]

Comment: While that will help, it'll also slow the execution of the code.

Comment: According to the documentation you can configure the settings to adjust the over head


"*Allow sampling to avoid the performance overhead on every request*"

Comment: Thanks, but isn't this that I want.

Answer (score 0):

define a class method, and then call it...

```
class Example

  def self.instantiate
    puts "Hello World!"
  end

  instantiate

end
```

testing in console...

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.22.4)
2.2.5 :001 > Example
Hello World!
 => Example
```

Comment: Thanks, it's almost, but try run two or more times, "Hello World!" will show only one time. :(

Comment: Thats because a class definition is constant. see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#class-and-module-definitions-are-constant-assignments the class method is 'instantiate' is called when the object is created. This object behaves like a singleton. subsequent calls to example will only ever return the constant.

Comment: You _could_ destroy the constant and redefine it e.g `Object.send(:remove_const, :Example)` then 'require 'example'' that will re-run the instantiate class method, but that seems excessive.

Comment: If I make this, an error is returned if I call the const again ```uninitialized constant AAnyClass (NameError)```.